# Angular 4 -Header Nav Bar Disappears

Tags: angular

I have a navigation bar on the top of the page with some Routing Links in it.
On Home page the Header navigation bar can be seen. But as soon as I Route to another Links the header navigation bar disappears.

How can i fix this?

- Please find the code below for navigation bar. It includes three
  routing links. When i click on Home header bar is seen.But when i
  click on other links it disappears.

Nav-bar.component.html-

```
<div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light">
  <ul class="navbar-nav" routerLinkActive="active">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/home']" matTooltip="Homepage!">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/table']" matTooltip="Information">Link1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/userinfo']" matTooltip="Userform">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select [(value)]="selected" >
          <mat-option value="option1" (click)="openSnackBar()">Option 1</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="option2" (click)="openSnackBar()">Option 2</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="option3" (click)="openSnackBar()">Option 3</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

This is the Homepage where i have called the Nav-Bar

```
<app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>

        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>Welcome to Clara</h1>
          <p class="alignp">Hello! {{name}}</p>
        </div>
```

1. On the "table" Link in navbar.component.html the below code comes
   but then here the nav bar disappears

.

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <div class="example-header">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
                 [pageSize]="10"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">

  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Then below is app.routes.ts

```
import { NgModule }              from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes }  from '@angular/router';
import {UserComponent} from "./user-component/user-component.component";
import {HomePageComponent} from "./home-page/home-page.component";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {UserFormComponent} from "./user-form/user-form.component";
import {InfoPageComponent} from "./info-page/info-page.component";
import {AppTabsComponent} from "./app-tabs/app-tabs.component";
import { StepperComponent } from './stepper/stepper.component';
import {TableComponent} from "./table/table.component";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'app', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'main',component: AppComponent},
  { path: 'user', component: UserComponent },
  { path:'home', component: HomePageComponent},
  { path:'table', component: TableComponent},
  { path:'userinfo', component: StepperComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Most probably in the other pages you do not kept the Navigation bar. Either your navigation bar should be outside of `router-outlet` or it should be present in all pages. Please post your code for better understanding.

Comment: Please see the code. mistakenly i posted it in Answers. :(

Comment: Add the code in your question. Please delete your own answer.

Comment: It is the code of your Nav-bar.component.html. But as you told it is not comming in certain pages so need the code of those pages and also the code of that page where it is comming.

Comment: Add your routing code too.. As a guess, I can say, you are using router outlet to load `NavbarCoponent` and `HomeComponent`, but on routing to other path, only one Component is being loaded, so the `NavbarComponent` getting destroyed.

Comment: I have called <router-outlet> only in app.component.html

Comment: I have posted the complete code now please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess was right...!! There is a catch.

In your `HomeComponent` you call `NavBar` + Some HTML content, which is perfectly fine. Now, understand the routing first, as soon as you load any component, it's constructor method gets called and component gets created, means the component is created and it will be shown in `<router-outlet>`, but when you route to other component, Angular destroys the previous component, and creates a new component that's being called and displays it again in the `<router-outlet>`.

So your code is correct, but the place you are putting your `Navbar` is incorrect.

To get `Navbar` on every page in your app, include your `<app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>` in your app-component, just above the `<router-outlet>` tag.

Doing this, will create the `NavbarComponent` but never destroys it till the app is running.

Hope this helps..!!

Comment: Ya i tried that and it would work.But the thing is before homepage i have a login Component as well where i dont want to show any nav bar.If i call my nav bar on app.component, then it is seen on login page as well

Comment: Got your point. Even when I was learning, I was having the same use case. :P

Comment: To do so, you should create a service, and use that service to decide whether to show or hide the navbar.

Comment: For workaround i just called the selector of navbar everywhere .I will try to create a service then.

Comment: can u give some idea for creating a service for this behaviour

Comment: Yeah, but for that, ask a separate question, cuz, this solution will confuse other users searching for the solution. :)

Comment: @Shweta Hey, please stop pinging others, this can be seen as rude and annoying. They will see your comment and return when they decide to do so.

Comment: @ModusTollens thanks for pointing out :) but she was in urgent need so she did.

Comment: @ManojShukla I understand. But she was also posting the call for help in the comment section several times without cleaning up, and some users downvote for that and for expressing the need for urgent help, so I stepped in to prevent that and "keep house".

Comment: @ModusTollens Yes...!! I'm sure now she'll be careful next time. Thanks. :)

Comment: @ModusTollens sorry about this will be careful next time

Comment: @ManojShukla how do i join then discussion room now with you?